# Does Git-Extensions support git lfs?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I couldn't find any information on that topic.

Since Git-Extensions uses mainly (or is it: only) the command line to work with the repository my assumption is, that it should be OK with git lfs.
Diff, Blaming, File-History etc. shouldn't be a problem since lfs will only handly binary files.

But since that part of Git-Extensions (Diff, Blaming, File History) is quite weak (does not behave quite deteministic in my opinion) I was wondering if we would run into a problem when using git lfs.

Has anyone reliable information/experience when working with Git-Extensions and git lfs?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not yet supported.

There has been a feature request issue open since Oct. 1, 2015.  As of April 2016, it has not yet been addressed.

- https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2968